# How to pass back control of a program to the calling function in a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.4

I have a little visual poker dice app I'm working on, and I'm adding a help screen that clarifies rules and payouts.  I'm running my program in a while loop, so currently whenever the help button gets pressed, it never breaks back out of the loop, even when the help function has completed.  Not sure exactly why.  Here are the two functions:

```
class PokerApp(object):

    def __init__(self, interface):
        self.dice = Dice()
        self.money = 100
        self.interface = interface

    def run(self):
        choice = self.interface.want_to_play()
        while self.money >= 10 and choice != "Quit":
            if choice == "Help":
                self.interface.help()
                self.run()
            else:
                self.play_round()
        self.interface.close()
```

Then my help function:

```
def help(self):
        rule_format = "{value:<20}{reward:>5}".format
        help_screen = Rectangle(Point(100, 300), Point(500, 100))
        help_screen.setFill("gray")
        help_screen.draw(self.win)
        help_title = Text(Point(300, 125), "Dice Poker Rules")
        help_title.setSize(16)
        help_title.setStyle("bold")
        help_title.draw(self.win)
        value_reward = [("Two Pairs", 5), ("Three of a Kind", 8), ("Full House", 12),
                        ("Four of a Kind", 15), ("Straight", 20), ("Five of a Kind", 30)]
        rule_start = [200, 260]
        rules = []
        for value, reward in value_reward:
            rules.append(Text(Point(*rule_start), rule_format(value=value, reward=reward)))
            rule_start[1] -= 20

        for index, item in enumerate(rules):
            item.draw(self.win)

        while True:
            p = self.win.getMouse()
            while not p:
                continue
            help_screen.undraw()
            help_title.undraw()
            [rule.undraw() for rule in rules]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have two unterminated `while` loops. The first `while` loop has no end condition and no `break` statements to exit the loop. This means that it will never end. Also, as soon as `self.win.getMouse()` returns a falsy value, `not p` will become true, and the inner `while` loop runs, doing absolutely nothing forever because `p` never changes. If you are intending to end the `help` function when `p` becomes false, you need to replace the inner `while` loop with and `if` statement and change the `continue` to a break. Also, do you really want to undraw everything after the first iteration? Corrected code:

```
while True:
    p = self.win.getMouse()
    if not p:
       break
help_screen.undraw()
help_title.undraw()
[rule.undraw() for rule in rules]
```

Comment: I want to undrawn everything as soon as they click on the screen again, if that makes sense.  Thanks for the help with the while loops!

Comment: @flybonzai I don't know what `self.win.getMouse()` does, but I was speculating that when it returned a falsy value, that meant the help screen was over and that was when you wanted to undraw things.

Comment: It just returns an x and a y coordinate for where the user clicked.  So basically the second while loop was to wait until they clicked again.

Comment: @flybonzai You should have stated that in your question. It seems like you want something like `while self.win.getMouse():pass` followed by `while not self.win.getMouse():pass` which would wait until the mouse is released then pressed.